# How can I import CSS within a Laravel Blade subview?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a home.blade.php that extends a layout, and @includes component.blade.php, which is the subview mentioned in the title.

Within the component there is the CSS and JS imports.

The question is: how should I properly import these CSS files within this component? I've tried @section and @stack/@push, but the imports won't show on layout's @section.

With JS it works just fine with @push:

```php
// component.blade.php
@push('scripts')
    <script src="{{ mix('/js/components/my-component.js') }}" type="module"></script>
@endpush

//home.blade.php
@extends('layouts.app')
@includes('component')

// layouts/app.blade.php
<body>
    // my code
    @stack("scripts")
</body>
```

***Considering that this method won't work with CSS because @stack only works after all the @pushes (which means I can't use it on `<head>`), how can I import these styles?***

Comment: Why won't this work with CSS? Just use a different stack.

Comment: You can use `@push`, there is no problem with that